# Fantom network external drive to internal to get data off (RAID)

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, raid

I had a network Fantom drive, that lasted 7 years.  Then one of the drives went bad.  The good drive I took out and hooked it to my computer and drive manager can see it.  But right now they are just primary partition with all that I can do is delete the partion to get space and start using it.  Nice but I want to get the old tax records and other stuff off of it first.

And I did put the information in the guest share so permissions should not be an issue.  (I hope)

Any Advice?

```
Fantom 2TB G-Force MegaDisk Network Attached Storage - 32MB, 7200RPM, RAID - NAS Ethernet Disk Storage
Windows 8 OS
```

Comment: Upon some investigation it seems to me your Fantom drive could have been configured as RAID0 or RAID1. **Which was it?** In case you don't know, look at disks capacities. If you had (before the failure) twice as much space (or slightly less) as your single drive provides then the answer is RAID0. If you had just as much space (or slightly less) as your single drive – RAID1.

Comment: RAID 1, I believe I set it up for Mirror

Comment: Boot live Linux (e.g. Knoppix). Assuming the disk in question will be `/dev/sda`, what is the output of `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda`? and `sudo blkid /dev/sda1`? In case it's not `/dev/sda` try also `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdb`, `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdc` and so on, until you identify it by matching size and partition layout.